# Scaling to different android screen size for google DFP ad - Phonegap

Tags: java, android, cordova, scaling, google-dfp

I'm working on developing an android app for our business website using Phonegap. Instead of splashscreen, we need to use a Google DFP creative prodided by our advertiser.

Issue with it is, The Google DFP loads successfully but it is not scaling even after trying our different 'meta' tag options.

1) meta id="testViewport" name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"

2) meta id="testViewport" name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"

3) meta id="testViewport" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1

and also various other combinations.

Also, tried by adding a javascript script function that sets DFP's height and width at runtime but turned out to be unsuccessful.

Many Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this... Logic is to get the screen size of the device and calculating the target scaling value based on device orientation.
This code has to be added in 'onCreate' method.

```
 // get actual screen size
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

// calculate target scale (ORIG_APP_W is max width of image, ORIG_APP_H is max height of image)
        double globalScale_Width = Math.floor( ( width / ORIG_APP_W ) * 100 );
        double globalScale_Height = Math.floor( ( height / ORIG_APP_H ) * 100 );

 // set the scale based on orientation
        if(deviceOrientation==getResources().getConfiguration().ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            super.appView.setInitialScale( (int)globalScale_Height);
        }else if(deviceOrientation==getResources().getConfiguration().ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            super.appView.setInitialScale( (int)globalScale_Width);
        }
```